# Writing large quantity of integers in a txt file in c

Tags: c, file, file-handling, filewriter, file-read

I wrote this code where I generate random integers in a large quantity and store them in a txt file. it works if I input up to 49 integers

[image: 1]

but after that it does not read any further from the file or the file don't accept any further I don't know please help me

[image: 2]

this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fptr;

    int num, n;

    fptr = fopen("integers.txt", "w");

    if (fptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("File created successfully!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to create the file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter some integer numbers [Enter -1 to exit]: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n != 0)
    {
        num = rand();
        putw(num, fptr);
        n--;
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    fptr = fopen("integers.txt", "r");

    printf("\nNumbers:\n");
    int count = 0;
    while ((num = getw(fptr)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d\n", num);
        count++;
    }

    printf("\nNumber of elements in the file %d",count);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text. Instead copy&paste your text (that also includes, input, output, any error messages, command, etc.) as formatted text into your question. We would need to type your numbers if we want to reproduce.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: And are you using the non-standard and MSVC-specific [`putw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/posix-putw?view=msvc-170) function?

Comment: What is `RAND_MAX` on your system? You should make sure, you don't try to write `EOF` into your file as you will not be able to distinguish getting `EOF` because you reached the end of the file or because that value was actually read from the file.

Comment: As for your problem, have you looked at the actual contents of the file? What is its data? Does it perhaps contain the value `-1`? Perhaps you need to spend some time with the [`_putw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putw?view=msvc-170) and [`_getw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getw?view=msvc-170) documentation?

Comment: and did you notice the output series are always the same? You haven't seeded the random generator

Comment: And a ***very*** important note: The `_putw` and `_getw` functions deals with *binary* data, they don't write and read text. You need to open your file in **b**inary mode.

Comment: @Gerhardh Interesting, I reacted to this, under Bugs:        The value returned on error is also a legitimate data value.  ferror(3) can be used to distinguish between the two cases.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, you're right.  Removed my comment, so as to not mislead.

Comment: You should better not use `getw` and `putw`, these are non standard Microsoft functions. Better use `fwrite(&num, sizeof(num), 1, fptr)` and `fread(&num, sizeof(num), 1, fptr)`. Also tell us if the content of integers.txt should be text (as the .txt extension suggests) or binary data. If it's text, you should use `fprintf` and `fscanf`.

Answer (score -1):

You have following problems:

- As you're writing binary data, the file needs to be opened with "wb" and "rb" (b stands for binary). Othwerwise certain unwanted text substitutions will take place.
- If one of your random numbers turns out to be -1, the read will stop prematurely because `EOF` has the value -1. Therefore you need to do the end of file check with the `feof` function instead of comparing the value read with `EOF`.

```
 fptr = fopen("integers.txt", "wb");   // <<< open with binary mode "wb"

 ...

 fptr = fopen("integers.txt", "rb");   // <<< open with binary mode "rb"

  printf("\nNumbers:\n");
  int count = 0;
  while (1)
  {
    num = getw(fptr);

    if (feof(fptr))   // end of file reached => stop the loop
      break;

    printf("%d\n", num);
    count++;
  }
```

**BTW**:

The [documentation of `getw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getw?view=msvc-170) concerning the return value is pretty misleading, especially the part *"A return value of EOF indicates either an error or end of file"* seems wrong to me. `getw` can read -1 values (0xffffffff) without problems.